# Insert rows from a table for each row of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, first is the 'group' table:

[image]

Second is the 'subject' table:

[image]

So I want to create a table 'marks' and insert rows 'id, first_name, last_name' from 'group' into 'marks' and then insert 'subject.name' into 'marks' so that each row in 'marks' gets all the 'subject.name' rows from 'subject', like this:

[image]
...

I've tried something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE marks 
SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM our_group.group;

ALTER TABLE marks ADD subject_name varchar(255);

INSERT INTO marks (subject_name) select name from subject;
```

but it did not work out

Comment: Hint : `CROSS JOIN`. Btw, I don't think creating a new table would have sense, just using a SELECT statement would give you the desired result.

Comment: Hint 2 : `SELECT INTO`

Comment: As if you're confused with `SQL Server` @tnavidi